# JunitXml reporter issues

Tags: xml, junit, jasmine, protractor, report

I am using Jasmine and protractor to run unit tests.

I have test suite that runs three spec files

```
suites:{
r = ['a.js', 'b.js', 'c.js']
},
```

I am planning to run Jenkins and needs JunitXml reports.

The problem is the suite will be run for a total of four times based on different use cases.

I need separate reports for each of these runs. Is there a way to do this?

One way is to save the report to another location after each run but I can't figure out a way to do that.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `JUnitXmlReporter` from `jasmine-reporters` you can either use `filePrefix` or `modifiySuiteName` to create distinct files or suite names. You don't say what the difference between the runs will be but the documentation for [multi capabilities](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/blob/master/README.markdown#multi-capabilities) show how to change name based on browser:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

    // returning the promise makes protractor wait for the reporter config before executing tests
    return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
        // you could use other properties here if you want, such as platform and version
        var browserName = config.capabilities.browserName;

        var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            savePath: 'testresults',
            // this will produce distinct xml files for each capability
            filePrefix: browserName + '-xmloutput',
            modifySuiteName: function(generatedSuiteName, suite) {
                // this will produce distinct suite names for each capability,
                // e.g. 'firefox.login tests' and 'chrome.login tests'
                return browserName + '.' + generatedSuiteName;
            }
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
    });
}
```

You can probably edit this to fit your needs or add some more details to the question about how the suite is run and what changes between runs.

Comment: I kind of solved the issue by adding the current date and time to the reports file prefix.